# How to retrieve Tag list when extracting user stories/features details via Rally REST API

Tags: rally, powerquery

I use Power Query to call the Rally REST APIs and retrieve data from Rally directly into Excel. I prefer it over the CA AGile Central ADd-In as it allows transformation of the data "on the way".

The problem is that when I try to include the Tags field in my queries, the tag column will return as a record. It has a _tagsNameArray element which is actually a list of records each containing a tag URL like this "/tag/82404838120".

Is there any way I can make the REST API call to return the tags NAMES in a concatenated list similarly to what is returned by the CA Agile Central Excel Add-in. For example: tag1,tag2,tag3

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The _tagsNameArray includes the names of each tag in addition to its ref, so you should have all the data you need.  I'm not familiar with power query, but I would think you should be able to format your results since the data is all there.